# Display data with the same title but different content

Tags: android, web-services, view, ksoap

Let's say if I have a database which contain:

> ID: 1 | Name: hello | Content1: sample1 | Content2: sample2

And I have developed a WSDL webservice which have the result like this:

```
<name> hello </name>
<content1> sample1 </content1>
<content2> sample2 </content2>
```

I have used `KSOAP2` to read the data from the webservice.

```
String NAMESPACE = "blablabla";
String METHOD_NAME = "RequestDetails";
String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
String URL = "blablabla";

try {
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 1000000);
    Log.i(TAG, "transport started and completed! ");
    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
    SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
    constructor.setName(resultString.get("name").toString());
    constructor.setContent1(resultString.get("content1").toString());
    constructor.setContent2(resultString.get("content2").toString());
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
list.add(construct);
```

And now I put this list into a customAdapter. Then, the result will be like:

Name
Content1
Content2

Is there anywhere for me to make the result be like?

Name
Content1
Name
Content2

As it is a listview, so i wish to have

Name
Content1 is position 0.

Name
Content2 is position 1.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is make listview_item_row as 
name
content1
name
content2

and while adding data to listview just check name and content, 
ex:

> if(content2 == null)

do not add name for content 2

> if(content2 != null)

then jsonparsing be like

```
constructor.setName(resultString.get("name").toString());
constructor.setContent1(resultString.get("content1").toString());
constructor.setName(resultString.get("name").toString());
constructor.setContent2(resultString.get("content2").toString());
```

Comment: hi @Rites. will ur way have the same position in listview? because i want i to be in different position. like Name content1 is position0 and Name content2 is positioni1

Answer (score 0):

try following apprach

create model class

> public class SampleModel {
>       String title;
>       String content;
>
> ```
> public String getTitle() {
>     return title;
> }
>
> public void setTitle(String title) {
>     this.title = title;
> }
>
> public String getContent() {
>     return content;
> }
>
> public void setContent(String content) {
>     this.content = content;
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> public class SampleClass extends AppCompatActivity {
>       @Override
>       protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
> ```
>     String NAMESPACE = "blablabla";
>     String METHOD_NAME = "RequestDetails";
>     String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
>     String URL = "blablabla";
>
>     List<SampleModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
>     try {
>         SampleModel model;
>         SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
>         SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
>         soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;
>         soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
>         HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 1000000);
>
>         transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
>         SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
>
>         model = new SampleModel();
>         model.setTitle(resultString.get("name").toString());
>         model.setContent(resultString.get("content1").toString());
>         arrayList.add(model);
>         if (resultString.get("content2").toString() != null) {
>             model = new SampleModel();
>             model.setTitle(resultString.get("name").toString());
>             model.setContent(resultString.get("content2").toString());
>             arrayList.add(model);
>         }
>
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     // here pass this arraylist to customListAdapeter
>
>     //list.add(construct);
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> }